# Darkening CSS background image without darkening the area under transparent card-panel

Tags: css, materialize

My web page contains with a background image and a tranparent card-panel on top of it. Is it possible to only darken the background image while keeping the brightness of the area under the transparent card panel the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on how the position and the shape of card you usually can. What I should do is:
-- create a **pseudo element** for the HTML element having the background image

-- stretch the **pseudo element** out to fit the whole area of the parent element

-- make sure that the **pseudo element** stay under the parent content (the card) in your case

-- Make the **pseudo element** look darker by adding a background to it, using **linear-gradient**.

By using **linear-gradient**, you can control which part of the background image look darker than the other part, the part which you don't want to look darker should have **linear-gradient** value as transparent. This technique will work fine most of the time for normal shape/position however, it has its own limit. I leave it for you to research how to use them.

In case you are not used to these terms and techniques, I put a few links below:

Pseudo element:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Linear Gradient as background:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp